# Passing array of vectors as a function parameter to change the original values

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, reference

I have an array of vectors (of ints) and I want to pass it to a member function as reference so it can be modified. (It actually is the output of my function but I already have a return value.)

I wrote something like this

```
int Dag::dag2array(vector<int> (&aVectors)[4])
{ 
//some stuff
//calling another function tree2array(aVectors) 
//passing the same array as reference
}
```

It compile and runs although it looks like it is not doing what I want.

In a more or less opposite question ([Passing array of vectors as a function parameter (values will not change)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24039087/passing-array-of-vectors-as-a-function-parameter-values-will-not-change)), the answers say that the array can be modified without `&` and that it does not make a copy but it is like a pointer.

1. Why for a variable like an `int` one needs the `&` to avoid
   copying and to be able to modify the value of the original variable "on the fly" and not for an array?
2. Should I use the `&` or not in my case?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What does the code actually do as opposed to what you want?

Comment: An array of vectors? That's just evil. Use C++ or C, not both!

Comment: Try `vector<vector<int>>&`

Comment: @NeilKirk: With vector<vector<int>>& the size of the first vector can be changed and in my case it is fixed so array<vector<int>, 4>& would make more sense. I just wanted to understand how it all works!

Comment: @SebastianRedl: My code does not change the array given as parameter (aVectors).

Comment: Then try `array<vector<int>, 4>&`

Comment: What is it doing that's not what you want? That code works...

Comment: If the array is actually a return value you could consider returning it in a `std::pair` or `std::tuple` instead of using reference parameters.

Comment: @ChrisDrew: I thought about using pair but it is actually in a recurrent function and dealing with return in the recurrence was way too complicated for me. I am an humble beginner in C++ ;-)

Comment: @Barry: If this code works, the cause for my array not being filled might lie somewhere else in the code. I'll keep looking. But at least I now understand arrays a bit better!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an array is passed to a function, its type is adjusted to a pointer to its first element.  Likewise a parameter declaration of the form `T[N]` is adjusted to `T*`. The pointer being passed is copied but the elements of the vector are not copied at all. This means when dereferencing the pointer you can still refer to the original array element through the array access syntax `array[n]` (which is really just pointer arithmetic: `*(array + n)`).

If you are passing an actual object to a function by value, a copy will occur so if you still want to modify the element you will need a reference.

So no, you do not need to pass the array by reference. Not unless you want to access the size of the array in the function (because the array-to-pointer decay discards the array size).

Answer (score 3):

This is one of those cases where C arrays just make life difficult. I would strongly recommend using a `std::array` (or `std::tr1::array` if you're not using C++11 yet). Rather than that obscure syntax, saying

```
int func(std::array<std::vector<int>, 4>& vectors)
```

makes it very clear that you're passing an array of 4 vectors by reference, and thus can modify the values by saying

```
vectors[1][2] = 19;
```

or what-have-you.